# How do I create an comparer for custom structs in Nunit 3?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I would like to use this NUnit 3 syntax to test structures like float3 and quaternion:

```
var expectedPosition = new float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
var position = new float3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.000001f);

Assert.That(position, Is.EqualTo(expectedPosition).Within(1e-5));
```

Right now `.Within()` seems to be ignored and the tiniest difference make the test fail, so I need to test each of the float3 components (i.e. x,y,z) one by one, which clutters my test code a bit.

I searched in the documentation but in the end I guess I don't know what I'm looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: This would work on an array of floats. Trick would be getting NUnit to treat float3, quaternion as if it's an array. Probably requires a feature request.

Comment: Eventually I used the `.Using()` method that allows to create your own comparer. It's not as fancy as `.Within()` but it works.